# I get sound but cannot playback videos ..?

Tags: windows-xp, video, audio

In ANY Windows player I get sound, but I cannot playback videos (any format). I uninstalled Windows media player and reinstalled it, I installed many codecs..... but now I realize that is not a codec problem.

display device:Mobile intel 4 series express chipset family

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the free player VLC, from http://www.videolan.org/vlc/.  This should help you figure out if there is something wrong with your video card / drivers / Windows installation or if you are just missing some codecs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to see what codecs are required to play that particular file. When using VLC one should not have to install any codecs since VLC has everything you need. It will also tell why it cannot play a particular file.

Other option would be to get the most up to date drivers for you Video Card.

You said you have re-installed Windows, you should have installed just the VLC and tried playing a video file then.